# How to write a LP/MIP to mark the items in a time-series list after a fixed delta?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling, constraint-programming

I have a time series list like this.

```
a = [1.1341, 1.13421, 1.13433, 1.13412, 1.13435, 1.13447, 1.13459, 1.13452, 1.13471, 1.1348, 1.13496,1.13474,1.13483,1.1349,1.13502,1.13515,1.13526,1.13512]
```

How to write constraints to mark after every 0.0005 change in this list using a LP/MIP (series is not sorted and order matters)

For example, `|a[0] - a[8]| = 0.00061 > 0.0005 and |a[16] - a[8]| = 0.00055 > 0.0005`

It's possible `a[16] < a[8]`. If MIP can be formulated such that output[16] = -1, it is most appreciated but just binary is also fine.

I am expecting something like the following. Output is the control variable in LP/MIP.

[image]

Is it possible to solve this just with constraints and without an objective function?

I want to solve this in CPLEX. Ideally I would like to formulate in regular LP/MIP but constraint programming is also fine.

Comment: It might be useful to explain briefly why you must use an LP/MIP solver for this. There are efficient sort+DP solutions, of course.

Comment: This is a part of a bigger problem which is MIP. I want to see if it's possible to write a constraint so that I can use it with rest of the MIP. Also, I am not familiar with DP

Comment: so in your example list a, split form of the list should be: a1= [1.1341, 1.13421, 1.13433, 1.13412, 1.13435, 1.13447, 1.13459, 1.13452, 1.13471], a2= [ 1.1348, 1.13496,1.13474,1.13483,1.1349,1.13502,1.13515,1.13526,1.13512] and a3=[1.13512] Is it the solution that you are looking for?

Comment: You can say so. I am expecting a variable list like [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0] once it is solved given a[16] < a[8]

Comment: If I understand your question as well, you would need to determine the sequence of the situations, in which the minimum absolute difference is at least 0.0005 between two numbers. Would you see this [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/98nqbbb9xcr9gjo/Results.txt?dl=0) that, it's what you are looking for?

Comment: @Omidi....actually no. This is time series data. I have 10k rows. I would like to mark rows whenever there is change of 0.0005. I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149499/how-to-cut-unsorted-time-series-data-into-bins-with-a-minimum-interval). Hope this clears the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each $i$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ be your desired output[i].  If I understand correctly, you want $x_0=1$, and for each $i<j$, you want $$(x_i,x_{i+1},\dots,x_{j-1},x_j)=(1,0,\dots,0,1)\iff \left(\bigwedge_{k=i+1}^{j-1} (|a_i-a_k|\le 0.0005) \land |a_i-a_j|> 0.0005\right).$$
Because $a_i$ is given, there is no decision to be made.  You can fix all $x_i$ up front, before calling any solver:

```
x[0] = 1
c = a[0]
for i = 1 to n
   if |c - a[i]| > 0.0005
      x[i] = 1
      c = a[0]
   else 
      x[i] = 0
   endif
endfor
```

---

### Update now that $0.0005$ is replaced with decision variable $\delta\in [0,U]$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small constant.  For each $i<j$, let binary decision variable $z_{i,j}$ indicate whether $|a_i-a_j| \le \delta$.
The following constraints enforce the desired relationship between $z$ and $\delta$:
\begin{align}
|a_i-a_j|z_{i,j} &\le \delta &&\text{for $i < j$}\\
-|a_i - a_j| + \delta + \epsilon &\le (-|a_i - a_j| + U + \epsilon)z_{i,j} &&\text{for $i < j$}
\end{align}

To enforce the logical proposition
$$\left(x_i \land \bigwedge_{k=i+1}^{j-1} z_{i,k} \land \neg z_{i,j}\right) \implies x_j,$$
impose the following additional constraint:
$$x_i + \sum_{k=i+1}^{j-1} z_{i,k} + (1 - z_{i,j}) - (j - i) \le x_j$$

Now the problem is to minimize the longest streak length $s$ subject to the above constraints and the following min-max constraints:
$$s \ge k \left(\sum_{j=i}^{i+k-1} x_j - k + 1\right)$$
for all $i\in\{0,\dots,n\}$ and $k\in\{1,\dots,n-i+1\}$.

Comment: You are spot on

Comment: OK, now is $a_i$ given or a decision variable?

Comment: a[i] is given. It's not a decision variable.

Comment: Is there a way to write it as a constraint. My actual problem is identify delta(0.0005) to minimize the longest streak of 1 in x. That's why I want this problem solution as a constraint instead of a loop assignment.

Comment: I tried to implment this solution in [CPLEX](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApMvJ4RzFb-N2CE28Y5Q06s9KajO?e=6rW5RB) and [ORTOOLS](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApMvJ4RzFb-N2CIwNKXGGZlsuPOO?e=cqmTFg) but I could not get the desired result. Is there any constraint I am writing wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but this formulation does not exploit the objective and is more complicated than it needs to be. I’ll provide something simpler later, unless someone else does it first.

Comment: I tried the updated formulation. Still no luck(CPLEX and ORTOOLS links above are updated). I know this is getting complicated without objective but it will help me in defining an another objective.

Comment: I updated the formulation just now.

Comment: I am updated my [CPLEX](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ADbxjlDTqz0pqM4&cid=8DBF157384272F93&id=8DBF157384272F93%2111297&parId=8DBF157384272F93%211744&o=OneUp) program but still I couldn't get the expected result.

Comment: The only thing I noticed is that you did not fix $x_0=1$.

Comment: I added x0=1. I am getting all 1s as the solution which is not correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106137/discussion-between-vinay-and-rob-pratt).

Comment: Corrected typo in my formulation: $1-z_{i,j}$ should have been $z_{i,j}$ in one constraint.